# Looping through query results with fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have moved away from mysqli_query() due to server requirements on a new project. However, I am having issues with updating some of my queries.

**Connection file**

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'nj2kfa3j_sublift');
define('DB_USER', 'nj2kfa3j_web');
define('DB_PASS', 'prum9wR4');
define('DB_CHAR', 'utf8');

class DB
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    protected function __construct() {}
    protected function __clone() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
            );
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }

    public static function run($sql, $args = [])
    {
        if (!$args)
        {
             return self::instance()->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = self::instance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
?>
```

**Problem Query Statement:**

```
$stmt = DB::run("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");
    $existCount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    if ($existCount == 1){
        $id;
        $full_name;
        var_dump($stmt);
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $full_name = $row["full_name"];
            echo 'test';
        }
}
```

I have done other queries in more or less the same way and they're working, like this:

```
$stmt = DB::run("SELECT * FROM categories");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

What is going on here? In the query above the var_dump() is returning:

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(81) "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='********' AND password='********' LIMIT 1" }
```

But it is not entering the *while* loop and hitting the echo 'test';

Comment: Because `fetchColumn` already fetches you a row. There's nothing to fetch anymore.

Comment: You should use a prepared statement and not store a plain-text password. Instead, use `password_hash()`.

Comment: Oh ok, that kinda makes sense. I had been looking into a few things and I seen something somewhere that said the fetchColumn() could be used like mysqli_num_rows() to see how many rows were returned. If I cannot do it this way is there any alternative for finding out if the query found a row or not?

Comment: use prepared statements please

Comment: @PaddyHallihan you can use `$existCount = $stmt->fetchall()` then use `count()` to see the number of rows returned, then lose the while loop and use `foreach`

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for your comment and getting me on the right track

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Thanks for the info which would be better count() or rowCount()

Comment: @PaddyHallihan `rowCount()` is not reliable on a `SELECT`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I was looking for an alternative to mysqli_num_rows() and found rowCount().

The following now works for me:

```
$stmt = DB::run("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");
$existCount = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($existCount == 1){
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). Your function is designed to accept prepared statements. Also, don't store your password as plain text; use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

You can fetch your results as an array with `fetchall()` and then count the array elements.

```
<?php
    $params = [$manager,$password];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username= ?  AND password= ?  LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
    $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Returns an array

    if (count($results) > 0){
        $id;
        $full_name;
        foreach($results as $key=>$row){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $full_name = $row["full_name"];
            echo 'test';
        }
    }
?>
```